# Wordpress Multisite giving users access to specific Admin Pages

Tags: multisite, admin-menu

In need of help here. I have a multisite installation and would want to give access to this page to .../wp-admin/admin.php?page=export to all users in the network.

Currently, I only have access to it when I am logged in to the network admin account. However, when I try it on a regular network account I get this error:

"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page"

Any tips on how I would be able to do this?

I do think that it is currently locked to admin users, any way that I can allow other users to access it.

Also I have read that it might be a database issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your database.
2. Figure out what your prefix is. The default is "wp_" but this solution will change if your prefix is different. Lets use "example_" for this.
3. Go to the your "example_options" table.
4. Find "SOMETHING_user_roles" and change it to "examaple_user_roles"